As Software engineer student How can i contribute to Ubuntu?
I’m a software engineering student and recently started using Ubuntu. One of my teachers mentioned that there are many open-source projects on Ubuntu, I don’t really have experience with Linux but I want to learn, so I was wondering how I could contribute to any of these projects.

This question is similar to: How can I contribute to Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have no idea what your teacher meant by 'many open-source projects on Ubuntu' as Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Server are both contributed by Canonical employees and the wider Ubuntu community, but they may have meant Ubuntu Desktop flavors which are all community run. You can contribute wherever you want; for me it's Ubuntu News, as well as flavors (Lubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE ..) or site such as this too... I'll provide https://ubuntu.com/community/contribute too, but there are many links & which is best will depend on what your interests/skills are

Welcome! Advice: Lurk in Ubuntu Discourse and AskUbuntu to learn the organization of the community, the arrangement of the software, and to discover contribution opportunities that you might find fulfilling. It's a complex community and complex software, so I suggest starting small.
